# I want to pick second latest value with reference to other cell in MS Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am currently using a formula which helps me in to pick the latest entry from column "C" by my given search word from (Column A) the bulk list of data with respect to time given in Column "D".

currently the formula I m using is

=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/('Price Recording'!$A:$A="CH7.2"),'Price Recording'!$D:$D),"Entery Manually")

[screenshot of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhO3H.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

*An array (CSE) formula with criteria, wrapped with `IFERROR` and `LARGE` can be used to solve the issue.*

[image]

- Formula in Cell `B45`:

  `{=IFERROR(LARGE(IF(A$31:A$43="CH7.2",B$31:B$43),2),"")}`

**N.B.**

- *Finish formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter***.
- *In the formula `2` specifies 2nd Latest/Largest, which is adjustable also.*
- *To make the formula dynamic `CH7.2` can be replaced with Cell reference.*
- *Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: **Need more help** Please go through my question again, your answer is only helping half of my question. what if i have to lookup a value from other column with respect to chosen 2nd largest value

Comment: @Tahirjamalkhan,, the suggested answer address and all around your question `pick second latest value with reference to other cell` and if you want to find value in adjacent column in respect of 2nd largest,, then better [Edit] your post and add this issue also. Or post a new question and one more post some sample data also !!

Comment: **Dear Rajesh** thanks for your kind understanding, you got it very right, I really want to find value in adjacent column in respect of 2nd largest. Kindly let me know if i need to re-share a screen shot

Comment: You need to [Edit] the post and below the Screen Shot Link,, add that, *other than current query my second need is to find adjacent cell's value in regard of 2nd Largest data* ,, then I'll post the formula.

Comment: I m having errors while posting the new question or editing the current one. :(

Comment: @Tahirjamalkhan,, if you need new formula then you must  modify the Question as I've suggested otherwise my new formula will not match the current issue !!